# Flutter: Open Drawer from a custom widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart, drawer

I used a custom widget in place of AppBar, but on tapping an icon (which is in place of the leading property of AppBar) it is not opening the `Drawer`.

How can I achieve this? I want to open the drawer from the custom app bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a GlobalKey and use openDrawer() method on it.

```
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _drawerKey = GlobalKey();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    key: _drawerKey, // assign key to Scaffold
    drawer: Drawer(),
  );
}

Widget _getAppBar(){
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
       Icons.person,
      ),
      onPressed: (){
        _drawerKey.currentState.openDrawer();
      },
    ),
  }
```